# how to solve logarithmic-quadratic inequality

Tags: calculus, logarithms, lambert-w

I was wondering if there is an analytical solution for the following inequality:

$ax^2 \le \log(bx), \quad x,a,b>0$

where $a,b$ are constants. It seems that this problem involves Lambert W-function, but it is still not very clear to me if there is an analytical solution in the form of

$x \le C(a,b),$

where $C(a,b)$ is the upper bound of $x$ determined by $a$ and $b$.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
 ax^2 &\le \ln(bx), \quad x,a,b>0
 \tag{1}\label{1}
 .
\end{align}

Considering limits, we have both
\begin{align} 
 \lim_{x\to0}ax^2 &> \lim_{x\to0}\ln(bx)
 ,\\
 \lim_{x\to\infty}ax^2 &> \lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(bx)
 \quad \forall a,b>0
 ,
\end{align}

thus there is no solution to \eqref{1}
unless there is intersection point(s),
which can be found in terms of Lambert $\operatorname{W}$ function,
for example, as:

\begin{align}
 ax^2 &= \ln(bx)
 \tag{2}\label{2}
 ,\\
 x^{-2}\ln(bx)&=a
 ,\\
 -2x^{-2}\ln(bx)&=-2a
 ,\\
 x^{-2}\ln((bx)^{-2})&=-2a
 ,\\
 (bx)^{-2}\ln((bx)^{-2})&=-2ab^{-2}
 ,\\
 \ln((bx)^{-2})&=\operatorname{W}(-2ab^{-2})
 ,\\
 (bx)^{-2}&=\exp(\operatorname{W}(-2ab^{-2}))
 ,\\
 x^{-2}&=b^2\exp(\operatorname{W}(-2ab^{-2}))
 ,\\
 x&=(b^2\exp(\operatorname{W}(-2ab^{-2})))^{-\tfrac12}
 ,\\
 x&=\frac1b\,\exp\left(-\tfrac12\operatorname{W}(-2ab^{-2})\right)
 \tag{3}\label{3}.
\end{align}
Note that we ignore potential negative solution since we are interested in positive $x$.
The argument $-2ab^{-2}$ of
the Lambert $\operatorname{W}$ function in \eqref{3}
is negative, and from the well-known properties of 
the Lambert $\operatorname{W}$ function,
we can deduce that there are only three possible cases,
depending on the values of $a,b$:

Case 1. There is no intersection for
\begin{align}
 -2ab^{-2}&<-\exp(-1)
 ,\quad\text{that is, no solution to \eqref{1}}
 .
\end{align}

Case 2. There are two intersections for 
\begin{align}
 -\exp(-1)&<-2ab^{-2}<0:
 \quad
 \begin{cases}
  x_1&=\frac1b\,\exp\left(-\tfrac12\operatorname{W}_0(-2ab^{-2})\right)
  ,\\
  x_2&=\frac1b\,\exp\left(-\tfrac12\operatorname{W}_{-1}(-2ab^{-2})\right)
  ,
 \end{cases}
 ,\quad\text{the solution to \eqref{1} is}\quad
 x\in[x_1,x_2]
 .
\end{align}

Case 3. There is only one intersection (touch) for
\begin{align}
 -2ab^{-2}&=-\exp(-1)
 ,\quad\text{the solution to \eqref{1} is just one value }\quad
 \\
 x&=\frac1b\,\exp\left(-\tfrac12\operatorname{W}_0(-\exp(-1))\right)
 =\frac1b\,\exp(\tfrac12)
 .
\end{align}

Illustration for $a=3$:

\begin{align}
 b_1&=3.5,\quad \text{no solution}
 ;\\
 b_2&=6,\quad x\in[\tfrac16\exp(-\tfrac12 \operatorname{W}_0(-\tfrac16)),
 \tfrac16\exp(-\tfrac12 \operatorname{W}_{-1}(-\tfrac16))])
 \approx[0.1846,0.6872]
 ;\\
 b_3&=\sqrt{6\mathrm{e}},
 \quad
 x=\tfrac{\sqrt6}6
 \approx 0.4082
 .
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

To solve $ax^2=\ln(bx)$:

$$2ax^2=\ln(b^2x^2)$$
Let $g=2ax^2$,

$$g=\ln(\frac{b^2}{2a}g)$$
$$e^g= \frac{b^2}{2a}g$$
$$\frac{-2a}{b^2}=-ge^{-g}$$
$$-g=W(\frac{-2a}{b^2})$$
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{-W(\frac{-2a}{b^2})}{2a}}$$

Now you can solve your inequality with suitably flipping the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function and its derivatives
$$f(x)=a x^2-\log (b x)$$
$$f'(x)=2 a x-\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f''(x)=2 a+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ Since $a$ and $b$ are positive, the first derivative cancels at a point
$$x_*=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a} }\implies f(x_*)=\frac{1}{2}-\log \left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a} }\right)$$ and the second deivative is stricly positive.

In order that $f(x_*) <0$ in some region, you then first need $$\log \left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2a} }\right) < \frac 12$$ and this will be true up to the solution of $f(x)=0$ given in terms of Lambert function as Szeto already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing $\epsilon$ we have

$$
a x^2=\ln b +\frac{1}{2}\ln x^2 +\epsilon^2
$$

and then

$$
e^{2ax^2}=2ax^2 \frac{b^2}{2ae^{2\epsilon^2}} \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2a}W\left(-\frac{2ae^{2\epsilon^2}}{b^2}\right)}
$$

but

$W\left(-\frac{2a}{b^2}\right) \le W\left(-\frac{2ae^{2\epsilon^2}}{b^2}\right) \Rightarrow x \ge \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2a}W\left(-\frac{2a}{b^2}\right)}$